# A Hausdorff compact space $X$ containing an uncountable discrete set $A$ such that $\overline{U}=\overline{U \setminus A}$ for every open set $U$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I would like to see an example of a Hausdorff compact space $X$ for which there exists an uncountable set $A \subseteq X$ such that:

- $A$ is a discrete space when equipped with the subspace topology;
- $\overline{U}=\overline{U \setminus A}$ for every open set $U \subseteq X$.

This question came to my mind when I was thinking about the compact interval $[0,1]$ and its subset $\big\lbrace \frac1n ; \, n \in \mathbb{N} \big\rbrace$. This set satisfies the two conditions above, but it is countable.

Comment: Maybe look at $[0,1]^\Bbb R$ and take $A$ to be the set of all elements that has $1/2$ in exactly one coordinate and all other coordinates 0?

Comment: How about $\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} A\subset \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} [0,1]$?

Comment: My impression is that $X$ cannot be metrizable if this situation occurs.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan: Yes, $X$ cannot be metrizable since metrizable compacta are second countable.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Thank you, this seems to work.

Comment: @DavidMitra, can you please post this as an answer so we can upvote it? I think this would be very beneficial for students who are searching.

Comment: Here's a question: would the second bullet point always hold?

Comment: Re, above: no, take $X=\{0, 1, 1/2,1/3,\cdots\}$ and $A=U=\{1, 1/2,1/3,\cdots\}$.

Comment: At first glance, I was wondering what this second bullet point means. But then I noticed that it is equivalent to the open kernel of $A$ being empty.  Hence, if $X$ has no isolated points, the second condition is implied by the first one. And such an $A$ exists, iff the spread of $X$ is uncountable.

Comment: @Bob Dobbs: no this does not work, since this space is metrizable (see jenda358's comment).

Comment: @Ulli in box topology?

Comment: @Bob Dobbs: Well, without further specification, I would always consider the product topology. Of course, the box topology is not metrizable. But it is not compact either.

Comment: @David Mitra: yes, the second condition holds, if $X$ has no isolated points and $A$ is discrete, see my comment above.

Comment: @Ulli I don't know what metrizabity is. I can't see why my example doesn't work.

Comment: @Bob Dobbs: A topological space is *metrizable*, if there is a metric on this set, which induces the given topology.  If you consider $\prod_{i=1}^\infty [0,1]$ with the product topology, it is metrizable and compact, hence, as pointed out by jenda358, it does not contain an uncountable discrete subset. On the other hand, if you consider it with the box topology, it is not compact.

Comment: @Ulli Not intiutive... Thanks.

Comment: Is this ok?: $\prod_{\Bbb{R}} A$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X=[0,1]^\Bbb R$ (with the product topology, of course). Let $A$ be the set of all elements $x\in X$ such that $x$ takes the value 1 in exactly one coordinate and the value 0 in all other coordinates. It is easy to verify (if you know [Tychonoff's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem)) that this does what you ask.